# How to store doc id when creating it using flutter and firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a Todo App and I need to access the ids of my documents stored in firestore in order to delete them. But I can't figure out how to save it when I'm creating it.
Here's the part in my Add screen where I create a new document.

```
 _firestore.collection('todos').add({
                    'title' : title,
                    'type' : type,
                    'date' : dayDate,
                    'time' : _dayTime,
                    'category' : category,
                    'author' : loggedInUser.uid,
                    //'id' : doc.id
                  
                  });
```

I don't know how to acess it. And also I display my tasks into cards and when i long press them I want them to delete from firestore but I can't bc I don't have their idea. Here's my empty function:

```
void deleteTask(){
_firestore.collection("todos").doc().delete();
}
```

If you have any ideas please tell me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

```
CollectionReference ref =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todos');

String docId=ref.doc().id;

await ref.doc(docId).set({
  'title' : title,
  'type' : type,
  'date' : dayDate,
  'time' : _dayTime,
  'category' : category,
  'author' : loggedInUser.uid,
  'id' : docId
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the doc id before like so `CollectionRef.pots.doc().id` you can then add it. This way you will have the docId also inside the doc which you can access when you have the doc data..

```
 static createPot(String name, String password) async{
    try{
      PotModel newPot = PotModel(
        name: name,
        potId: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('pots').doc().id, // will generate a random doc id, which will be used to create the next document
        password: password,
        ownerId: ViewModelUser.user.value.mobile,
        createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
        isActive: true,
        potActions: [],
        users: [ViewModelUser.user.value.mobile]
      );
      /// creating a new pot
      DocumentReference documentReference = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('pots').add(newPot.toJson());

      return newPot;
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with the collectionRef but it saves me a different id than the actual one. Is it normal? I wrote that:  'id' : todos.doc().id

Comment: in the example i showed above ##CollectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('pots')## it will generate a new doc id every time, so when you create a new doc, you can also get its id before its creation to save inside the doc

Comment: Using this answer you can save the id to the doc (even if its different) and when you are calling the function to render the list you can add each doc id to each corresponding item in the list so you can use it as a reference to find the document you wish to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm a bit late but If anyone else is stuck here is how you can store doc id when creating it

```
CollectionReference ref =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todos');

    await ref.doc(ref.doc().id).set({
                    'title' : title,
                    'type' : type,
                    'date' : dayDate,
                    'time' : _dayTime,
                    'category' : category,
                    'author' : loggedInUser.uid,
                    'id' : ref.doc().id
                  
                  }).then((value) {
            // Do something
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      print(stackTrace);
    });
```

To delete the specific collection

```
void deleteTask(){
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todos').doc(docId).delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first I update the document, that is, I save the collection, second it is updated, here is the example, I hope it helps you: Although there are two queries, I think it saves us from not using more in the future:

```
DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> newOrderRefA =
                      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('ordenes')
                          .add({
                    'fecha': DateTime.now(),
                    'sectorEntrega': sectorIngresado,
                    'nombreLocal': nombreLocal,
                    'uidCuestomer': user.uid,
                    'phoneLocal': numeroLocal,
                    'tokenNotificacion': userToken,
                    'stateOrder': 'open',
                    'metodoPagoEfectivoRealizada': metodoPagoSeleccionado,
                    'esNoViableEntrega': false,
                    'province': provinceLocal,
                    'sectorWork': sectorWork,
                  });
                  print(newOrderRefA.id);
                  String uidOrden = newOrderRefA.id;

                  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('ordenes')
                      .doc(newOrderRefA.id)
                      .update({'uidOrden': uidOrden});
```

Good Luck